# Why daisy() in cluster library failed to exclude NA when computing dissimilarity

Tags: r, cluster-computing

According to `daisy` function from `cluster` [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/daisy.html),
it can compute dissimilarity when NA (missing) value(s) is present.

> In the daisy algorithm, missing values in a row of x are not included
>   in the dissimilarities involving that row. There are two main cases,
>
> If all variables are interval scaled (and metric is not "gower"), the
>   metric is "euclidean", and n_g is the number of columns in which
>   neither row i and j have NAs, then the dissimilarity d(i,j) returned
>   is sqrt(p/n_g) (p=ncol(x)) times the Euclidean distance between the
>   two vectors of length n_g shortened to exclude NAs. The rule is
>   similar for the "manhattan" metric, except that the coefficient is
>   p/n_g. If n_g = 0, the dissimilarity is NA.
>
> When some variables have a type other than interval scaled, or if
>   metric = "gower" is specified, the dissimilarity between two rows is
>   the weighted mean of the contributions of each variable. Specifically,
>
> d_ij = d(i,j) =   sum(k=1:p; w_k delta(ij;k) d(ij,k)) / sum(k=1:p; w_k
>   delta(ij;k)).
>
> In other words, d_ij is a weighted mean of d(ij,k) with weights w_k
>   delta(ij;k), where w_k= weigths[k], delta(ij;k) is 0 or 1, and
>   d(ij,k), the k-th variable contribution to the total distance, is a
>   distance between x[i,k] and x[j,k], see below.
>
> The 0-1 weight delta(ij;k) becomes zero when the variable x[,k] is
>   missing in either or both rows (i and j), or when the variable is
>   asymmetric binary and both values are zero. In all other situations it
>   is 1.
>
> The contribution d(ij,k) of a nominal or binary variable to the total
>   dissimilarity is 0 if both values are equal, 1 otherwise. The
>   contribution of other variables is the absolute difference of both
>   values, divided by the total range of that variable. Note that
>   “standard scoring” is applied to ordinal variables, i.e., they are
>   replaced by their integer codes 1:K. Note that this is not the same as
>   using their ranks (since there typically are ties).
>
> As the individual contributions d(ij,k) are in [0,1], the
>   dissimilarity d_ij will remain in this range. If all weights w_k
>   delta(ij;k) are zero, the dissimilarity is set to NA.

But why when I tried this code

```
library(cluster)
x <- c(1.115,NA,NA,0.971,NA)
y <- c(NA,1.006,NA,NA,0.645)
#z <- c(1.115,1.3,2.2,0.971,NA)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(x,y))
daisy(df,metric="gower")
```

It gave this message:

```
Dissimilarities :
   x
y NA

Metric :  mixed ;  Types = I, I, I, I, I 
Number of objects : 2
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I expect the dissimilarity output gives a non-NA value e.g. 0.
What's the right way to do it?

How can I replace the NA from `daisy()` output with 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can do so, but it needs at least one non-missing value. In your example `x` had `NA` in items 2, 3 and 5, and `y` in 1, 3 and 4 out of five items. Either or both elements were missing in every pair. How do you suggest dissimilarity be assessed in such cases? I have no clue.

Comment: Sorry for quick reading. It seems that you were prepared and willing to have NA values, but wanted (for an obscure reason) to treat them as identical cases. If `d` is a dissimilarity object with `NA` values, you can use `d[is.na(d)] <- 0` to replace those `NA` values with `0`. I don't understand why to do so, but that is none of my business.